# How to compare a specific string with all elements of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare

I'm reading in from a file that has a hex value on each line. It will look like this:

```
F0BA3240C
083FA52
45D3687AF
etc.
```

The hex values won't have the same length.

I have fgets reading from this file into a buffer and then a piece of code to get rid of the newline character. From there I put the string from the buffer into my data array. But before putting the string from the buffer into my data array, I'm attempting to compare the string from the buffer to the strings already stored in the data array and see if there is or isn't a match so I can update some counters. However, I'm having issues using strcmp and strncmp. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Relevant code:

```
char **data = NULL;
char data_buffer[100];

//program first goes through the file and determines amount of lines there are hence this variable
int count_line              = 0;
...
data = malloc(count_line * sizeof(char *));
int f;
int i;
for(i=0; i<count_line; i++) 
    {
        fgets(data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), fp);

        ...

        //allocate space to store copy of line and add one for null terminator
        data[i] = malloc(line_length + 1);

        ...
        if(asdf != NULL)
        {
            //problem here. don't know how to compare stream from buffer and compare to all elements of data buffer
            for(f=0; f<sizeof(data); f++)
            {
                if(strcmp(data[f], data_buffer) == 0)
                    there_was_a_match++;
            }

        }
        ...
        //copy string from buffer into data array
        strcpy(data[i], data_buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these lines:

```
        for(f=0; f<sizeof(data); f++)
        {
            if(strcmp(data[f], data_buffer) == 0)
                there_was_a_match++;
        }
```

What is the value of `sizeof(data)`? Since `data` is of type `char**`, presumably 
`sizeof(data)` is the size of a pointer in bytes, so some fixed integer value such as 4 or 8.
Now observe that the first time you encounter this loop within the "for i" loop,
`i` is 0 and `data[0]` is the only pointer in the array of pointers that has been allocated--
every other pointer in `data` is invalid.
So now what happens is, we do the first iteration of the inner loop: `f` is 0, so we
end up comparing the string we just read to itself.
On the next iteration, `f` is 1, we try comparing our latest string to `data[1]`,
but `data[1]` has not yet been initialized, 
ergo we have undefined behavior (such as a crash).

You might be better off if the `f` loop were like this:

```
        for(f=0; f<i; ++f)
        {
            if(strcmp(data[f], data_buffer) == 0)
                there_was_a_match++;
        }
```

This way, you will compare the newest string (which you have just saved in `data[i]`)
with only the strings that were already loaded.

There is one other thing that may be troublesome. Suppose your input consists of four
copies of the same string.
Then after you read the second copy and execute this loop, `there_was_a_match` will be 1; 
after reading the third copy and executing that loop, `there_was_a_match` will be 3
(because it matches twice); 
after reading the fourth copy and executing that loop, `there_was_a_match` will be 6.
I suspect these are not the results you want.
Perhaps you want to break out of the loop after finding the first match.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t see problems with strcmp/strcpy, but:

```
for(f=0; f<sizeof(data); f++)
```

You can´t use sizeof, ie. it won´t result in the value count_line.
From the shown code, this could be enough to make it work.

Comment: If I change it to some integer number e.g. 50 it still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe describe the problem you´re encountering?

Comment: I'm using Pelles C and when trying to compile I get no errors but it crashes when I attempt to run the code. If I take out **if(strcmp(data[f], data_buffer) == 0)**, it executes fine.

Comment: Wait a moment...did you say you inserted 50? ... As chux said too, you can only use what´s currently there. The first time it reaches this line, there are not 50 or more entries saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare to the previous allocated lines, which is `i` lines.

```
// for(f=0; f<sizeof(data); f++)
for(f=0; f<i; f++)
```